# How to include only sources of maven module itself in intellij package view

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I imported a maven multi-module project into intellij. If I now expand a module in the package view, it not only shows the sources of the module itself but also all the sources of the modules the module depends on.

Is there some setting to make the view behave more like the eclipse project explorer, where it shows only the sources of the project itself, not the sources of the dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue will be [fixed](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/IDEA-65722) in IDEA 10.0.3.

Comment: Good to know. It currently prevents me from switching to IDEA.